# using JSON object in Qt

Tags: javascript, qt

I'm trying to make a small weather app in Qt for which I'm using the world weather online API in JSON format.I just made a simple text section and tried to print the recieved data from the JSON feed.
import QtQuick 2.0

```
Rectangle {
TextInput {
    width: 240
    id: city_label
    text: "Chicago"
    font.family: "Helvetica"
    font.pointSize: 12
    color: "#000000"
    focus: true
}

function abc()
{
var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
doc.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (doc.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
       var jsonObject = eval('(' + doc.responseText + ')');
       loaded(jsonObject);
    }
}

doc.open("GET", "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=" + city_label.text + "&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=640bc6c793043201130202");
doc.send();
}
function showRequestInfo(text) {
    log.text = log.text + "\n" + text
   console.log(text)
}

function loaded(jsonObject)
{
    showRequestInfo("cloud:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].cloudcover);
    showRequestInfo("humidity:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].humidity);
    showRequestInfo("observation_time:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].observation_time);
    showRequestInfo("precipMM:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].precipMM);
    showRequestInfo("pressure:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].pressure);
    showRequestInfo("temp_C:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].temp_C);
    showRequestInfo("temp_F:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].temp_F);
    showRequestInfo("visibility:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].visibility);
    showRequestInfo("weatherCode:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].weatherCode);
    showRequestInfo("weatherDesc:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].weatherDesc[0].value);

    showRequestInfo("weatherIconUrl:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value);
    image1.source = jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value;

    showRequestInfo("winddir16Point:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].winddir16Point);
    showRequestInfo("winddirDegree:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].winddirDegree);
    showRequestInfo("windspeedKmph:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].windspeedKmph);
    showRequestInfo("windspeedMiles:" + jsonObject.data.current_condition[0].windspeedMiles);

    showRequestInfo("Location:" + jsonObject.data.request[0].query);
}


width: 800
height: 1280

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        Qt.quit();
    }
}

Text {
    id: log
    width: 360
    anchors.top: parent.top;
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
    anchors.margins: 10

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as in a webbrowser you have access to native JSON.parse and JSON.serialize within the QML code.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring about qjson. It provides apis for parsing and serializing json objects. If you are using Qt 5 then QJson is probably included in Qt libs itself.

Comment: If you use Qt5, you should use Qt JSON (included in Qt Core) instead of qjson (external library).